# leftCols result assignment to the same matrix causes Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, eigen

See the following code

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;

int main(int argc, char**) {

    MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(4096, 4096);
    MatrixXf B = A.leftCols(1000); // <-- works fine
    std::cout << "--------" << std::endl;
    A = A.leftCols(1000); // <-- SegFault
}
```

Is there any problem with assigning the result of leftCols to the same matrix?

GCC - 4.8.4 (no spacial flags used) 
Ubuntu - 14.04
Eigen - 3.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [aliasing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html) issue, in `operator=` the destination `A` is first resized, and then the expression `A.leftCols(1000)` becomes invalid. You need to call [conservativeResize](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a712c25be1652e5a64a00f28c8ed11462):

```
A.conservativeResize(NoChange,1000);
```

or introduce a temporary:

```
A = A.leftCols(1000).eval();
```